# Does Hunspell dictionaries work in Pycharm and others Jetbrains products?

Tags: ide, dictionary, spell-checking, hunspell, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm to develop projects both in French and English, my whole system is `en_US.UTF-8`-based so does my `Pycharm`.

After skimming the [Pycharm doc on spell-checking](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/spellchecking.html) I added the `hunspell` dictionaries directory to `Pycharm` and keep only:

```
/usr/share/hunspell/fr_FR.dic
/usr/share/hunspell/en_US.dic
```

### Problem

This has **no effect on the spell-checker**.

Does Pycharm and other Jetbrains products support the hunspell `.dic` format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm an engineer responsible for spellchecking subsystem in JetBrains products now.

[Hunspell plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10275-hunspell) was recently added to plugins repo to support this kind of dictionaries, so you may install it and you will be able to add hunspell dictionaries to PyCharm and other JetBrains products.

The details can be found at: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2018/01/hunspell-dictionaries-support/

Answer (score 0):

Reading more thoroughly the doc I catch this sentence:

> The words in such dictionaries are delimited with the newline.

However, the `hunspell` file look like:

```
affluent/2      1
affluente/5     4
affluer/43      17
afflux/6        7
affolante/5     4
affolement/2    1
affoler/12      13
affolir 216
affolée/5       6
```

Also there is no plural-forms in this files so *nombreuse* will be identified, but not *nombreuse**s***